# Error handling and session SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a table a user has to fill out consisting of whole/decimal numbers. I have my "save" function in a `try/catch` block so that if anything happens to fail, I could catch the exception message and return it to the user.

```
    try:
        UpdateMyList(my_list, request)

        return exc.HTTPFound(request.route_url("edit"))
    except Exception as ex:
        return default_edit_page(request, "Unexpected error:"+str(ex))
```

What seems to be happening is that when I encounter an error, instead of returning to the same page with my error message, it gives me an "InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to previous exception during flush". The point of all this is to avoid getting this screen [image], I'm basically trying to fail gracefully rather than just have that screen show up to the user when he accidentally entered a string instead of an int

Stack trace:

```
2014-10-31 08:39:06,933 ERROR [waitress][Dummy-2] Exception when serving /edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\waitress-0.8.8-py2.7.egg\waitress\channel.py", line 337, in service
    task.service()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\waitress-0.8.8-py2.7.egg\waitress\task.py", line 173, in service
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\waitress-0.8.8-py2.7.egg\waitress\task.py", line 392, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 242, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 217, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.0.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid_debugtoolbar\toolbar.py", line 160, in toolbar_tween
    return handler(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid_tm-0.7-py2.7.egg\pyramid_tm\__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid_tm-0.7-py2.7.egg\pyramid_tm\__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\views.py", line 355, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\views.py", line 501, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "C:\Users\pce-coop\Desktop\testingz\PCE Testsheets VS2012\PCE Testsheets VS2012\pce_test_sheet_program\views.py", line 2297, in edit_view
    return default_edit_page(request, "Unexpected error:"+str(ex))
  File "C:\Users\pce-coop\Desktop\testingz\PCE Testsheets VS2012\PCE Testsheets VS2012\pce_test_sheet_program\views.py", line 1896, in default_edit_page
    for id, val in DBSession.query(TJob.ixJob, TJob.sJobNumber).all():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2300, in all
    return list(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2412, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2425, in _execute_and_instances
    close_with_result=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2416, in _connection_from_session
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 854, in connection
    close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 858, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(engine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 305, in _connection_for_bind
    self._assert_active()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 214, in _assert_active
    % self._rollback_exception
InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)') u'UPDATE [tCableSet] SET [decCableSetThree]=? WHERE [tCableSet].[ixCableSet] = ?' (u'ee', 60)
```

Comment: Are you able to see the stack trace of the "unexpected internal server error" in the server logs? It seems likely the problem is caused by something you haven't shown us yet!

Comment: yes I am, I will post it.

Comment: Since `UpdateMyList` isn't part of the stack trace, it seems that the error is coming from a different part of your code. The part of the stack trace that (I'm guessing) is your code is `C:\Users\pce-coop\Desktop\testingz\PCE Testsheets VS2012\PCE Testsheets VS2012\pce_test_sheet_program\views.py`, `line 2297, in edit_view` and `line 1896, in default_edit_page`. I'd have a look at the code there and see if you can find the problem...

Comment: the reason it's giving me that line as the problem is that when I initially try and save the data input of the table to the database and it encounters an error (ex: user inputs 'wwwe' instead of a decimal), then on that line I am making a query to get other data but because my session has encountered an exception from a previous transaction, it need to either restart the session or deal with it in an alternative manner

Comment: so have you tried creating a new session, or beginning a new transaction in the existing session, after you encounter the first error?

Comment: I have not because I feel like it's dealing with the problem in an incorrect way(dealing with validation/exceptions at the wrong level). I was planning on either just making my validation 100% client side before even submitting the post. The original post was maybe to more so get input from what best practices would be to dealing with exception crashing the site and not having the user sit with a screen showing a message they can't understand. (still fairly new to python)

Comment: You probably can't make validation 100% client side. E.g. what if two browsers submit exactly the same request at exactly the same time? Front end validation will pass, but the backend will only allow the DB row to be added once.

Comment: any suggestions to dealing with this then? Only other thing I can think of is perhaps jquery validation or deforms

Comment: Create a new session, or begin a new transaction in the existing session, after you encounter the first error.